# Changing an image's src before appending in jquery

Tags: jquery

The user is uploading an image that has the id `imgLogoOr`. I am creating a `div` with an image inside (`#logo`).

I want this image to have as `src` the image from `#imgLogoOr` and then to be appended in a `div` with id `text_content`.

Here is the implementation I thought but the `src` remains empty whatever I try. Is there a way to fix that?

```
$('input[name=add_logo]').on('click', function() {
    var myLogo = $("#imgLogoOr").attr("src");
    var divLogo = $('<div class="one_text" style="left: 75px; top: 50px;"><img id="logo" src=""><div class="del"></div></div>');
    $("#logo").attr("src",myLogo); //also tried "myLogo"
    $("#text_content").append(divLogo);
    $(".one_text").draggable({
        containment: "#text_content",
        scroll: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it in the string:

```
var divLogo = $('<div class="one_text" style="left: 75px; top: 50px;"><img id="logo" src="' + myLogo + '"><div class="del"></div></div>');
```

The reason your implementation is not working is because the element doesnt exist on the DOM, therefore your selector never matches.